# Prove that $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-nx}\sin{(n\pi x)}$ is infinitely many times differentiable on $(0, \infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

> Prove that $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-nx}\sin{(n\pi x)}$ is infinitely many times differentiable on $(0, \infty)$.

I have managed to prove just single time differentiability using almost uniform convergence of series of derivatives.

Comment: What's the derivative of a single term in the sum?

Comment: $n e^{-nx} (\pi \cos{(n \pi x)} - \sin{(n \pi x)})$

Comment: Are you required to use uniform convergence to solve this problem? For otherwise you can find an explicit closed form of $f$ which can be easily shown to be infinitely differentiable.

Comment: I'm not required to use any specific method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1.** One can find an explicit formula of $f$. Indeed, for $x > 0$ we get

$$ f(x)
= \operatorname{Im}\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-nx(1-i\pi)} \right)
= \operatorname{Im}\left( \frac{1}{1-e^{-x(1-i\pi)}} \right)
= \frac{e^x \sin(\pi x)}{e^{2x} - 2e^x\cos(\pi x) + 1}. $$

Since the right-hand side is infinitely differentiable on $(0, \infty)$, so is the same for $f$.

**Method 2.** For each $k \geq 0$, let

$$ f_k(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \operatorname{Im}\left[ (n(i\pi-1))^k e^{nx(i\pi-1)} \right]. $$

Then for any $\delta > 0$, Weierstrass M-test together with $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} n^k e^{-n\delta} < \infty$ shows that $f_k$ converges uniformly on $[\delta, \infty)$. So $f_k$ is differentiable on $[\delta, \infty)$ and $f_{k+1}$ is the derivative of $f_k$ for each $k \geq 0$. In particular, $f = f_0$ is infinitely differentiable on $[\delta, \infty)$. Since this is true for any choice of $\delta > 0$, $f$ is infinitely differentiable on $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: I like very much your first method, but now I try to compute imaginary part myself and I have no idea how to get to the form you've got. Could you please show some more steps?

Comment: @user4201961, Sorry, I forgot to reply to your comment. The usual trick of figuring out $\operatorname{Im}(1/z)$ for a complex number $z=a+ib$ is to utilize the identity $$ \frac{1}{a+ib} = \frac{a-ib}{(a+ib)(a-ib)} = \frac{a+ib}{a^2+b^2}. $$ In your case, the denominator is $1 - e^{-x}e^{i\pi x} = (1-e^{-x}\cos(\pi x)) + i\sin(\pi x)$ by the Euler's identity, so you may plug $a = 1-e^{-x}\cos(\pi x)$ and $b=\sin(\pi x)$ and proceed.

Answer (score 3):

On any interval $[a,b]$ with $0<a<b<\infty$ the series $\sum_n n^{k} e^{-nx}\sin (n\pi x)$ converges uniformly for every positive integer $k$. Hence you only have apply the following lemma repeatedly:

if $\sum f_n$ and $\sum f_n'$ both converge uniformly on $[a,b]$ and if the sums are denoted by $f$ and $g$ respectively, then $f$ is differentiable and $f'=g$.

Comment: I understand the argument for $[a,b]$ but how do we extend it to $(0,\infty)$ Thanks I mean do we have to take something like a sequence of intervals $I_n=[n,n+1]$

Comment: If a function on $(0,\infty)$ is infinitely differentiable on $[a,b]$ whenever $0<a<b<\infty$ it is obviously infinitely differentiable on  $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: I don't see how derivatives of your series relate to derivatives of $f$.